# Reading Table from SAP ECC using SAP JCo

Tags: java, saprfc, sap-basis, sapjco3

I want to print details of all Transport requests, I am trying to read data in table `E070` from SAP ECC using SAP JCo and `RFC_READ_TABLE`, I am running the following code but I am getting no output.

Here is the code:

```
import com.sap.conn.jco.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Transport {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Transport.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Configure logger
        LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);

        // Establish connection
        JCoDestination destination;
        try {
            destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("SAP-ECC-Dest");
            destination.ping();
        } catch (JCoException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Connection error", e);
            return;
        }

        // Create function module call
        JCoFunction function;
        try {
            function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");
        } catch (JCoException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Function module error", e);
            return;
        }

        // Set up function module parameters
        JCoParameterList imports = function.getImportParameterList();
        imports.setValue("QUERY_TABLE", "E070"); // Table name for transport requests
        imports.setValue("DELIMITER", "|"); // Set delimiter for the result

        JCoParameterList tableOptions = function.getTableParameterList();
        JCoTable data = tableOptions.getTable("DATA");
        // System.out.println(data);
        // Add filters if required
        // imports.setValue("OPTIONS", ...);

        // Execute the function module call
        try {
            function.execute(destination);
        } catch (JCoException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Function module execution error", e);
            return;
        }

        // Process the results
        String[] rows = data.getString().split("\\|");
        for (String row : rows) {
            String[] columns = row.split("\\|");
            if (columns.length >= 3) {
                String transportRequestId = columns[0]; // Request ID column
                String description = columns[2]; // Description column

                logger.info("Transport Request ID: " + transportRequestId);
                logger.info("Description: " + description);
                logger.info("-----------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried debugging it but nothing worked. Thank you :)

Maybe someone with more experience can tell me how should I configure this sample code in order to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code worked for me:

```
import com.sap.conn.jco.*;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
public class TransportRequestDetailsExamples {                                                                                                                                  
    public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                                                                                        
        try {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("SAP-ECC-Dest");                                                                                          
            destination.ping();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            JCoFunction function= destination.getRepository().getFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            JCoParameterList imports = function.getImportParameterList();                                                                                                               
            imports.setValue("QUERY_TABLE", "E070");                                                                                                                                    
            imports.setValue("DELIMITER", ";");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            JCoParameterList tableOptions = function.getTableParameterList();                                                                                                           
            JCoTable data = tableOptions.getTable("DATA");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            function.execute(destination);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            System.out.println(data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        } catch (JCoException e) {                                                                                                                                                      
            e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```